# If simple product has parent product,Join simple product review to group product

Tags: grouped-products, magento2.3.0

I want to join simple product review to there parent product,if the simple product is associated with any product,then the review will also attached to the paent product

Comment: It still angers me that this problem still exists in M2 unresolved. Grouped products disappear on order, it is the simple product that is added to cart and in order details etc. Request for reviews send link to simple product. But grouped product does not show those reviews.
I figured it out in M1 but now needed in M2. And none of the review extensions cover grouped products either.

Comment: did you ever find an extension or solution?